# Python: sklearn PCA mean convert to opencv2 RGB image

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, pca

Iam trying convert PCA mean to RGB, but i get error: `cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3642: error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor` this error was caused by line `mean = cv2.cvtColor(mean, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`

My code:

```
def featureExtract(self, images, dim, k = 4):
    faces_rowvecs = []
    nDim = None
    for image in images:
        image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        nDim = image.shape 
        faces_rowvecs.append(image.flatten("C").copy())
    faceData = np.vstack(faces_rowvecs)
    pca = PCA(n_components=k)
    pca.fit(faceData)

    mean = pca.mean_
    mean = mean.reshape(nDim[0],nDim[1], nDim[2])
    mean = cv2.normalize(mean, dim, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    mean= cv2.cvtColor(mean, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Comment: your `mean` matrix is not of type `uint8`, `uint16` nor `float32`. Try with something like: `mean = cv2.normalize(mean, dim, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=uint8)` and then call `cvtColor`

Comment: This works but if i want do `cv2.imshow('image',mean)`  then image is black. When i do `cv2.imshow('image',mean)`  before `cv2.cvtColor(mean, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)` i see correct image.